# neo4j 2.0.0 with spring data neo4j

Tags: spring-data-neo4j, neo4j

Neo4j 2.0.0 was released. so I update neo4j version 2.0.0.M6 to 2.0.0.RELEASE.
And try to update Model in my webSite but exception is occured.

> org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: Unique
>   property class java.lang.String rankStatId rel: false idx: true was to
>   be set to duplicate value 3073631_99

MY SDN version is 2.3.2.
SDN 2.3.2 cann't support Neo4j 2.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the comment way at the bottom of this post: http://blog.neo4j.org/2013/12/neo4j-20-ga-graphs-for-everyone.html

Michael Hunger states that SDN 3.0.0-M2 will support neo4j 2.0, so we need to be a bit more patient I'm afraid.